# Comparing the significance of multiple group frequencies in R

Tags: r, frequency, control-group

Suppose I have sum of frequencies from 4 groups with:

```
df <- data.frame(groups=c("trt1", "trt2", "trt3", "control"),
                    sum_freq=c(139, 276, 88, 174))

df
   groups sum_freq
1    trt1  139
2    trt2  276
3    trt3   88
4 control  174
```

I wanted to test whether the sum_freq from either trt1, trt2 or trt3 is higher than the control group. I also have the raw freq from each individual in each group. I am wondering what is the best method for this test?

Comment: What distinction are you making between `sum_freq` and "raw freq"?

Comment: raw freq such as `trt1-ind1 5`, `trt1-ind2 7`, `trt1-ind 6` .... the `sum_freq` is the sum of all inds in each group.

Comment: Asuming simple random sampling (you did not tell us), try a multinomial model (so you are conditioning on the total count.) Let the probabilities be $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3, \pi_c$. Your hypothesis seems to be that at least one of the $\pi_i > \pi_c$. Can you verify?